# Error in py.test in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

When i run pytest on my system, it gives an error: no tests ran in 0.01 seconds . Can someone tell me if its because of error in my code or some other reason.

Output is :

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.11, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /Users/Desktop, inifile: 
collected 0 items

========================= no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You really need to show a much better [mcve] than this. Chances are you are just not pointing to the right location for pytest to know what to run. What command are you running, how is your project structured (i.e. where are your tests located). Did you follow a tutorial to ensure that you have everything configured as it should?

Comment: It couldn't find any tests to run, and therefore did not run any.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon , appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same issue, the fix is to change the rootdir.

Go to `Setting->tools->externaltools` and set the parameters as `"$FileName$"` and working directory as `"$FileDir$"` for your pyTest

[image: Screenshot showing where to enter]